# How to create a scatter plot with non-numbers as values?

Tags: highcharts

I have data of the form `["10.237.77.82","10.237.79.255"]` which I would like to plot on a scatter plot.

Highchart crashes with [error 14](https://www.highcharts.com/errors/14): `String value sent to series.data, expected Number`, which is correct as my data are indeed strings.

**Is there a way to use strings as the elements of a scatter plot?**

Comment: How do you envision the points are shown? Highcharts has no idea what to do with them since they will all fall on x, 0 with a string definition. If you asked me to make you a scatter plot of IP addresses, I would have no idea what you were after.

Comment: @ewolden: if I have 10 strings (indeed IP addresses in my case, but strings in general) on the x axis and 10 on the y, a dor on the plot would show that the element made out of two values (one from x, the other for y) is in the data set. This is not different from numbers.

Comment: So you basically want something like a [heatmap](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap) but in a scatter format then?

Comment: In short, values must be numbers @Woj However, your data looks like a categorized one, then maybe you just need this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8hc7Lzyu/1/ ? As you can see, categories (IP's) are on axes, but markers are numbers.

Comment: @PawełFus: thanks - in the meantime I found in the Highcharts demos which somehow looked like what I was trying to accomplish and ended up using your solution. It is not as straightforward as just feeding in numbers which will "place themselves" in the graph but it covers my needs. If you would be kind enough to post it as an answer I would gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, values must be numbers. However, dataset looks like a categorized one, then maybe you just need this: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8hc7Lzyu/1? As you can see, categories (IP's) are on axes, but markers are numbers.

Snippet:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  xAxis: {
    categories: ["10.237.77.82", "10.237.79.255"]
  },

  yAxis: {
    categories: ["10.237.77.82", "10.237.79.255"]
  },

  series: [{
    data: [
      [0, 1],
      [1, 0]
    ]
  }]

});
```